# Android OpenCv Image Processing

Tags: android

i am trying using `opencv` to take the image from the camera, and in real time display the same image 4 times on the screen. But i manage to display the image only once, can you give me some advice...

This is the xml code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:opencv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        tools:context="com.example.opencv.opencv.MainActivity">



        <org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/javacameraview"
            />



    </RelativeLayout>
```

And this from the MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2 {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    JavaCameraView javaCameraView;
    Mat mRgba;


     BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallBack = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
         @Override
         public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
             switch (status){
                 case BaseLoaderCallback.SUCCESS:{
                     javaCameraView.enableView();
                     break;
                 }
                 default:{
                     super.onManagerConnected(status);
                     break;
                 }
             }

         }
     };


    static {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        javaCameraView = (JavaCameraView)findViewById(R.id.javacameraview);
        javaCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
        javaCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        if(javaCameraView!=null){
            javaCameraView.disableView();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void  onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        if(javaCameraView!=null){
            javaCameraView.disableView();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        if(OpenCVLoader.initDebug()){
            Log.d(TAG,"OpenCV merge");
            mLoaderCallBack.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
        } else{
            Log.d(TAG,"OpenCV nu merge");
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_2_0,this,mLoaderCallBack);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
        mRgba = new Mat(height,width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStopped() {
        mRgba.release();
    }

    @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();

        return mRgba;
    }
}
```

Comment: If i get u correct, u have to add 4 views to display images either in xml or java code.

Comment: What does 'times' mean in "4 times"? Displaying the image 4 times with 1 second of each display? :S Or displaying it in four different views at the same time?

Comment: 4 different views at the same time. Now this code only shows one.